# the combo box editor in cell editing grid does not deselect after choosing a value

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc, sencha-cmd

I am having an editor grid with four columns and i am trying to implement a sql builder. The where statement will have four fields namely "condition1" "operator" "condition2" "and/or".
I am using a combo box to select between and/or/none and there is a delete button as row action. when I delete a row and if that row is the last,the value of and/or combo in the previous row will be set as "none". I am able to achieve that but the problem is , when the combo box is **selected** in the previous row and i delete the row next to it, the value changes in the store but not in the view. the value changes in the view when the combo box is **not selected** in the previous row.
my code is :

```
if(rowIndex == grid.all.endIndex)
   {
    //get the previous record and set the vale to none
    var previousRowRecord = grid.store.getAt(rowIndex-1); 
    previousRowRecord.set('andor','NONE');
    //delete the current record
    grid.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
    grid.getView().refresh();
   }
else
   {
     grid.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
   }
```

How to deselect a combo box once the value is selected ? i think this can be a work around

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly (a screenshot would help out a lot here), but it may sound like the combo box is still in the edit state when you are deleting the row below. If so, try the following:

First make sure the grid editor plugin has an id:

```
plugins: [{
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    ...
    pluginId: 'celleditplugin'
}],
```

Then, before deleting the row, do the following:

```
yourGrid.getPlugin('celleditplugin').completeEdit();
```